# How do I inject an EJB in Spring MVC using annotations?

Tags: spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, ejb

My dispatcher-servlet.xml has basically:

```
<context:component-scan base package="package.ejb" /> 
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

In the @Controller class I have:

```
@Controller
public class ApplicationController {
    @EJB(lookup="java:global/MyEarName/MyWebModuleName/BeanImplementation!package.ejb.morepackages.BeanImplementation")
    private MyBeanInterface myBean;
```

This didn't work, it looks like Spring doesn't see the @EJB annotation and it gives an error at deploy time saying it doesn't find any Autowire candidate. So I added the following code:

```
   @Autowired 
   @Qualifier("BeanImplementation")
   public void setMyBean(MyBeanInterface myBean) {
       this.myBean = myBean;
   }
```

And on my bean implementation:

```
@Component("BeanImplementation")
@Stateless(mappedName = "BeanImplementation", name = "BeanImplementation")
@LocalBean
public class BeanImplementation implements MyBeanInterface {
```

It worked, but I need to use the lookup string of the EJB and I can't since Spring doesn't see @EJB. I was forced to revert to a non-Spring application to use @EJB(lookup="...").

So, to clarify the question: how do I inject an EJB in Spring MVC using annotations and using the EJB lookup string? Thanks.

Comment: I had the same problem with springboot injecting ejb in ibmwebsphere [separate apps, same container]. I can confirm it does not work. IBM support & forums were not useful. They usually direct you not to use Spring! Great customer service :).  What I did was, expose ejb as webservice, and use springboot to connect to that webservice.